# Something is wrong when I try to implement scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, glibc

I wanted to implement a `scanf()` and I found an [implementation](http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/3.x/src/lib/libc/scanf.c) (I named it `new_scanf()`), which uses `fgets()` to take inputs from specific stream in `vfscanf()`.

This is my test program,

```
int main() {
     int a, b;
     new_scanf("%d", &a);
     new_scanf("%d", &b);
     printf("a=%d b=%d", a, b);
}
```

This program is worked when I type

```
123 <enter>
456 <enter>
a=123 b=456 ;program shows result correctly
```

But something is wrong when I type

```
123 456 <enter>
;the program is stuck here waiting for another input. scanf() should
```

not be stuck here

This behavior of `new_scanf()` is different from glibc's `scanf()` and I don't know how to solve it, can anyone tell me how to emulate `scanf()` perfectly?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Do you understand the `new_scanf` implementation? If not, what specifically don't you understand? And have you attempted to debug the problem in any way at all?

Comment: @kaylum if I understood correctly, he wrote `new_scanf`

Comment: @tobi303 My understanding is that OP took the `new_scanf` off the Internet. OP has linked to that. So I'm asking whether OP actually read the code and tried to understand and debug it.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. This looks like C. If you compile as C++, change the tag to C++, but not both.

Comment: @kaylum the scanf in the link is called `scanf` and before the edit he called it "my implementation". However, without any code it is hard to say what he is talking about.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express my question very clearly. I "guess" the problem occur in fgets() so I have not traced vsscanf() line by line, which is the format string handling. (In fact, vsscanf() in my implementation is not equal to the the code in link totally).

Answer (score 3):

Of course you cannot implement `scanf` using `fgets()` to read the input stream, you must carefully read one byte at a time with `getchar()`, `getc(stdin)`, or `fgetc(stdin)` and put back the first byte that should not be consumed with `ungetc()`.  Implementing `scanf()` correctly is a difficult task.  A complete implementation that handles all options and formats is **very** difficult.

The implementation you quote has a warning at the beginning of the file:

```
/*
 * ** This not been very well tested.. it probably has bugs
 */
```

It only handles unqualified integer formats `d`, `o`, `u`, `x` and non standard `b`, and character `c` and string `s` formats. No support for `long`, `long long` or any other type variants, no support for floating point, many instances of `strncpy`, most of which incorrect... Not a good base for your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that I should re-post my question later.